# Why do php files start with "<?php"? What happens?

Tags: php, tags

I tried searching here and using my Google-foo but really couldn't find a thorough explanation.  Can someone spread some light on this?

Comment: if some one call Boni, then you come to know that the person is talking about you. Same thing when you for <?php this tells server that following statement is in php and start parsing.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that PHP can be mixed with HTML markup, so the `<?php ?>` blocks define which parts of a PHP&HTML document contain PHP code.

Comment: It is not only <?php it is <?php[Whitespace]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which are  which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the code between them. Parsing in this manner allows PHP to be embedded in all sorts of different documents, as everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser.

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 0):

I found on [the manual this snippet](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php):

> The point of the example is to show the special PHP tag format. In
>   this example we used `<?php` to indicate the start of a PHP tag. Then we
>   put the PHP statement and left PHP mode by adding the closing tag, `?>`.
>   You may jump in and out of PHP mode in an HTML file like this anywhere
>   you want.

Comment: and isthis the answer you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

since many languages are written under C/C++ the `<?php` tell the compiler to execute any code as 'php' until `?>` and yes, it a function that already exist in C/C++